# Simple http get request not showing up in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to get info from this API :

In my main.js file I have this controller which is requesting an http request:

```
        (function(){
    var app = angular.module('provider',['provider-movies']);

    app.controller('ProviderController',['$http',function($http){
        var provider = this;
        provider.movies =[];

        $http.get('/http://private-5d90c-kevinhiller.apiary-mock.com/angular_challenge/horror_movies').succes(function(data){
            provider.movies = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

Then in my html I'm trying to print the title of the movie like this:

```
   <div ng-controller="ProviderController as provider">       
    <p>{{provider.movies.title}}</p>       
   </div>
```

But when i load the file on the browser it just shows this:

```
{{provider.movies.title}}
```

Angular is installed and working, if I add `{{'hello '+'you'}}` it prints `**hello you**`

Any ideas on why is this not working ?

Also , my html looks like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="provider">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css">
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

   <div ng-controller="ProviderController as provider">       
        <p>{{provider.movies.title}}</p>  
       <p>{{'hello'}}</p> 
   </div>


        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to have some typo and a missing closing parenthesis. If you looked at the console of your webbrowser you should definitely seen this.

Try this:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('provider', []);

    app.controller('ProviderController', [ '$http', function($http) {
        var provider = this;
        provider.movies = [];

        $http.get('http://private-5d90c-kevinhiller.apiary-mock.com/angular_challenge/horror_movies').success(function(data) {
            provider.movies = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

Also in your markup the `provider.movies` is an array which doesn't contain a `title` property:

```
<div ng-controller="ProviderController as provider">
    <p>{{provider.movies}}</p>       
</div>
```

If you wanted to have the `title` you may consider looping through them:

```
<p ng-repeat="movie in provider.movies">
    {{movie.title}}
</p>
```

And here's the [`working plunkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnvG6o3VVXEJTY7xcUOo?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks! that worked. But how do I print out the all the titles of the movies in the array then ? Thanks again :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to illustrate this. You loop through them using the `ng-repeat` directive: `<p ng-repeat="movie in provider.movies">{{movie.title}}</p>`.

Comment: Thanks so much! im new to angular and this is for a job application, im a bit closer to the goal now... :)  thanks mate!